# Simple Apache Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Folks,

This is easy, but I cannot seem to get this right, any help appreciated.

I if someone goes to a URL

```
http://test.api.com/somestuff I want it to redirect to 
http://test.api.com/en/api/somestuff
```

However my rewrite rule keeps resulting in a endless redirect - can someone spot the error?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/en/api/).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/api/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (the slash in the RewriteRule regex is the main difference):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/api/.*
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/api/$1 [R,L]
```